# python list index out of range in k-tuple sorting

Tags: python, sorting, radix-sort

I want to implement k-tuple sorting in least time i.e. O(k(m+n)) time.

My code is:

```
A = [(1,2,1),(2,3,1),(1,4,2),(2,2,2),(1,4,3),(3,2,1)]
B = [[] for _ in range(5)]

n = len(A[0]) - 1

for j in (n,0,-1):
    while(len(A) != 0):
        a = A.pop(0)
        B[a[j]].append(a)
    for l in range(5):
        A.append(B[l])

print(A)
```

I am getting error at `B[a[j]].append(a)` as index is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to implement a radix sort.

The line `A.append(B[l])` is wrong because you add the list `B[l]` as the last element of list `A` instead of adding **the elements of `B[l]`** at the end of list `A`. This is what causes `a[j]` to trigger `IndexError` as `a = []` in the second iteration of the for loop.

Then your outer for loop should use `range(n, -1, -1)` which returns `[2, 1, 0]` if `n==2` (see the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)).

Also `B` needs to be empty for each iteration of the outer loop.

```
A = [(1,2,1),(2,3,1),(1,4,2),(2,2,2),(1,4,3),(3,2,1)]

n = len(A[0]) - 1

for i in range(n, -1, -1):  # range(start, stop, step)
    B = [[] for _ in range(5)] # B needs to be empty for each iteration
    while(len(A)):
        a = A.pop(0)
        B[a[i]].append(a)

    for j in range(5):
        A += B[j] # Adding elements of B[j] to the end of A

print(A)
```

Comment: @sam I edited the answer as I realised you were probably after a radix sort.

Answer (score -1):

seems you forget to append something at B[0], you start appending list to position 1 and 2. Here is what you are doing

```
>>> A = [(1,2,1),(2,3,1),(1,4,2),(2,2,2),(1,4,3),(3,2,1)]
>>> B = [[] for _ in range(5)]
>>>
>>> n = len(A[0]) - 1
>>>
>>> for j in (n,0,-1):
...     print("j:%d" % j)
...     while(len(A) != 0):
...         a = A.pop(0)
...         print("appending %s at position %s" % (str(a), str(a[j])))
...         B[a[j]].append(a)
...     print("B:" + str(B))
...     for l in range(5):
...         print("l:%d" %l)
...         A.append(B[l])
...     print("A:" + str(A))
...
j:2
appending (1, 2, 1) at position 1
appending (2, 3, 1) at position 1
appending (1, 4, 2) at position 2
appending (2, 2, 2) at position 2
appending (1, 4, 3) at position 3
appending (3, 2, 1) at position 1
B:[[], [(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1)], [(1, 4, 2), (2, 2, 2)], [(1, 4, 3)], []]
l:0
l:1
l:2
l:3
l:4
A:[[], [(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1)], [(1, 4, 2), (2, 2, 2)], [(1, 4, 3)], []]
j:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Although the display of variables is useful to understand what a program does, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: How I said above, he doesn't populate the first element of the list B, so the prorgam fails. Starting from this, as you correctly suggest, he can performs the fix populating it in the proper way.. Anyway the answer was not clear about he's asking and poor of details.